# Bicep training. how to get maximum from it?

Tags: upper-body-workout

What is the fastest way of building massive biceps?
I weigh 75kg. I am5 '11'' tall. I take 150gms of proteins.  I do 5 sets of barbell and dumbell curls each. My biceps currently is 14 inches. I work out my biceps thrice a week . I gradually increase the weight of barbells(7.5-12.5kgs) and dumbells (10-20kgs). 
What else can be and needs to be done?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken from my rant on another question:

[No gain after 4 months of continuous excercise](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/31885/no-gain-after-4-months-of-continuous-excercise/31894#31894)

When you're a natural lifter (no anabolic supplements like 90% of the instagram and gym rat population), the most efficient way to grow is systematically, maybe even the only way. For those not using buckets of steroids, hypertrophy (muscle growth) is not a localized process. For the most part, given sufficient stimulus, muscle growth happens all over your body instead of in one teeny location. As such, doing work that stresses the whole body – putting a big load on the spine that the entire body must support – will cause more growth in your biceps than working the biceps directly. To put it another way, doing heavy trap-bar deadlifts will do more to make your arms bigger than doing curls. A popular rule of thumb in the lifting world states that in order to gain an inch of circumference on your arms, you need to gain about 15 pounds of muscle, and that's pretty much right. Otherwise you'd see guys walking around who trained nothing but biceps and, as a result, were inverse T-Rex types with huge arms and tiny little bodies. But you don't.So Curls Don't Work? Of course they do. A biceps-specific program will surely add some arm size as long as you're doing everything else right, but the results would generally pale in comparison to what you'd get if you did a program that was biased towards the deadlift or some other big, total body movement. Likewise, a biceps-specific program would help if you've been doing the big movements all along but need an area-specific catalyst. Steroids, however, make your whole body ultra-responsive to any kind of mechanical stress. If you're using sufficient quantities of steroids, anything works. All those body part-specific routines issued through countless bodybuilding mags "written" by bodybuilders did us all a huge disservice. They convinced many of us to concentrate on curls, kickbacks, shrugs, anterior delt raises, and leg extensions when we should have spent a lot of that time putting big systemic loads on our spine with compound movements.

You can't just work out biceps 3x a week, when you're not on any steroids, and expect to get bigger biceps. At least, not after you make the most of your "newbie" gains. Go do some heavy barbell/dumbell rows, pullups, rack pulls.

Moreover, obviously the "curl" is more or less the only way to directly isolate the biceps, but if you always do the same stuff, you'll look the same. You need to introduce new stimulus. Your biceps will adapt  (especially since you do this three times a week) very quickly to the two exercises that you are doing currently. You need to hit them from new angles, do preacher curls, do incline curls. You need to hit them from new grips, do reverse curls, hammer curls. You need to hit them with new intensities and tempos, do heavy curls, do supersets, dropsets, rest-pause.

Finally, OK, you take 150g of protein, which isn't bad. But are you actually eating a caloric surplus? You can eat 200g of protein and that will only be 800 calories still, you need to figure out your resting metabolic rate, i.e your maintenance level calories, and eat at least 500 calories more than that level.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are drug free, there is **no** “fastest way” of building **any** muscle group.  Muscle growth is a long term contract in which you agree to train consistently, eat nutritionally sound foods, recover effectively and continue the process for a **long** time.  Any so called “fastest way” typically tends to be at the risk of your health.

From your limited training description, I would suggest that you are training biceps too often.  Considering that you'll get some supplementary work (for biceps) from the other exercises you do for other body parts, and, you leave yourself open to over training your arms.  You should also consider symmetry and proportion when training different body parts.  Having large upper arms at the expense of the rest of your physique, in my opinion, is not a good goal.

We all tend to have one or more stubborn body parts that just don't seem to respond.  That's not to say you can't improve what you have.  Take a closer look at what you are doing for arm training.  Can you use different equipment, change the number of sets/reps, change the exercises?  Sometimes, a simple adjustment in your training can help you overcome a training plateau and aid in muscular growth.